# NULL values when trying to import CSV in Azure Databricks DBFS

Tags: python, csv, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

I'm trying to import a CSV file that has no headers into DBFS for Azure Databricks, but, no matter whether I use the UI or try to do it by code, the output shows null values for all the four columns.

Here's the code I ran:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *

# File location and type
file_location = "/FileStore/tables/sales.csv"
file_type = "csv"

# Options

delimiter = ","

customSchema = StructType([\
    StructField("id", StringType(), True),\
    StructField("company", IntegerType(), True),\
    StructField("date", TimestampType(), True),\
    StructField("price", DoubleType(), True)])

# Dataframe from CSV
df = spark.read.format(file_type) \
    .schema(customSchema) \
    .option("sep", delimiter) \
    .load(file_location)

display(df)
```

And the output I get is:

[image: Databricks Output]

What is happening here? If I don't define any schema it loads the data perfectly, but then I don't have the chance neither to specify the headers nor to specify datatypes.

Comment: You may checkout the read CSV files using custom schema : https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/data-sources/read-csv.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I uploaded a sample csv file to test your script, which content is as below.

```
1,Company-A,2019-09-30,10.01
2,Company-B,2019-09-29,20.02
```

Then, I tried to reproduce your issue successfully as the figure below, and I think the issue was caused by the incorrect type for the struct field `company`.

[image]

So I tried to use `StringType` instead of `IntegerType` for the field `company`, then it works fine, as the figure below.

[image]

Meanwhile, if the value of the `date` field is just a date, you can use `DateType` instead of `TimestampType` and the result as the figure below.

[image]

By the way, there are two other solutions for your needs.

1. Use the [`spark.read.csv`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrameReader.csv) function with `schema` parameter to read a headless csv file, as the code and figure below.

   ```
   df = spark.read.csv(file_location, schema='id INT, company STRING, date DATE, price DOUBLE')
   display(df)
   ```

   [image]
2. Use `pandas` package to read the csv file from `dbfs` file path on Azure Databricks first, then to create a Spark DataFrame from the pandas dataframe, as the code and figure below.

   ```
   import pandas as pd
   df_pandas = pd.read_csv('/dbfs/FileStore/tables/sales.csv', header=None, names = ['id', 'company', 'date', 'price'])
   df = spark.createDataFrame(df_pandas)
   display(df)
   ```

   [image]

Comment: Nice one Peter Pan!!